# Use system environment variables in env_files in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have an env file called myenvfile.env which is wanted to be defined from a system environment variable.

**.env**

```
SYSTEM_ENV_VAR=prefix
```

**myenvfile.env**

```
MY_COMPOSED_ENV_VAR=${SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}_suffix
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myservice:
    env_file: 
      - env_files/myenvfile.env
```

But when I create container with `docker-compose up -d`, I look into the container environment variables, and `MY_COMPOSED_ENV_VAR = "${SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}_suffix"` instead of desired `"prefix_suffix"`.

How can I achieve that? Thanks

**Edit: More information**

> If I define SYSTEM_ENV_VAR in Jenkins job, for example, it works in Linux and Windows. But if I try to do it in a shell, it doesn't work in Windows.

Comment: Is .env also file? How it is used?

Comment: @GintsGints, I've already posted `.env` content. If you have any idea, tell me please.

Comment: This is a very Windows-centric question. Linux doesn't even _have_ a concept of separate "user" and "system" environment variables (they're strictly per-process attributes, and nothing but).

Comment: I'm not separating "user" and "system" environment variables, but "system" (which I can access in shell) and "inside-docker" variables. For example, I want to parametrize an IP address and I want to define different dockers, each one composing its variable such as `MYVAR=${IP_ADDR}:${MYPORT}/anystring/`. I need MYVAR inside docker (that's why I define it in myenvfile.env) and I have IP_ADDR in my system.

Comment: When you say "in my system" -- which _specific_ processes? And in particular, is it set in the process _that starts the `docker-compose` command_?

Comment: If the problem is that Jenkins isn't inheriting environment variables you're setting up for your user's interactive shell, f/e, that's a very distinct issue (and not specific to Docker at all).

Comment: Ok. Clear. .env is file. But when it gets used?

Comment: @GintsGints, it's used automatically when you do `docker-compose up` in the same directory `.env` is, exporting these variables as system env.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `SYSTEM_ENV_VAR` before the `docker-compose up` command, something like:

```
$ export SYSTEM_ENV_VAR=test
$ docker-compose up
```

You'll see that it'll expand correctly.

This behaviour happens because the `SYSTEM_ENV_VAR` is expected to be declared previous to the `docker-compose up` command, as it'll not expand with environment variables that are declared in the container creation instant (the `env_file` key section, for example), only
the ones that are already available when the `docker-compose` runs.

That's why the Jenkins job works in this case.

Comment: No, I tried this and it doesn't work if you do `export SYSTEM_ENV_VAR=test` before `docker-compose up`. It works in linux if you do `source env.sh` and inside **env.sh** you have that export. By the way, how can it works with docker for Windows?

Comment: Are you running the export in the same `bash` session as the `docker-compose up`? I've tested in [linux](https://gist.github.com/gkawamoto/81000e7a8f5e7741150fd678fcc15a71) and [Windows](https://gist.github.com/gkawamoto/a9f4abd5f05804745b21407ada5b8181), as well as [checked the source code](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/980ec85bf45b6dc34cd4f37bf7736832337e7fe1/compose/config/environment.py#L38). Seems like there's something missing in the question. Also, what's `env.sh` in your context?

Comment: Yes, I'm running in the same bash. env.sh is in my context.

Comment: Yes, but how do you run `env.sh`? Would you mind expanding your question to include those steps (`env.sh`, `docker-compose up`, etc), as well as including information about your session running those commands (Linux bash, Windows CMD, Jenkins pipeline, etc)?

Comment: exactly. If i run `env.sh` in linux it doesn't work. If I run `source ./env.sh` in Linux it works. In Jenkins it works. In windows CMD it **doesn't** work.

Comment: I believe `env.sh` contains a `export SYSTEM_ENV_VAR=test`, right? That's because environment variables in Linux are restricted to it's bash shell, as well as it's children pids. What `source` does is just run the contents of a file inside the current shell. Try `./env.sh` then `echo $SYSTEM_ENV_VAR` and you'll see that the variable is not available.

Comment: Yes, `env.sh` contains `export SYSTEM_ENV_VAR=test`. I thank you try to help me, but unfortunately it's not helpful for me, because that information doesn't solve my problem in Windows CMD, and it's nice to know why, but for linux I've got already a solution using `source`

Comment: If you check the [Windows test](https://gist.github.com/gkawamoto/a9f4abd5f05804745b21407ada5b8181) I mentioned in a [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63798921/use-system-environment-variables-in-env-files-in-docker-compose-yml/63803676?noredirect=1#comment112835358_63803676), you'll see that things work pretty much the same as in Linux.

Comment: I'm telling you that the env file `env_files/myenvfile.env` **doesn't** compose correctly `MY_COMPOSED_ENV_VAR=prefix_suffix`, but `MY_COMPOSED_ENV_VAR=${SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}_suffix`. My issue is not related to any python example, is just about env composing. And the env composing works with `source` command in Linux, not with `export` directly, and doesn't work in Windows. That's my problem. If you cannot help me, no problem, I'll go on trying to solve, but, please **telling me that it works in your computer** is not solving me the problem in mine.

Comment: Can you reproduce it and print MY_COMPOSED_ENV_VAR content inside docker? That's what I need, not SYSTEM_ENV_VAR. Note that MY_COMPOSED_ENV_VAR should have been defined from SYSTEM_ENV_VAR.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221213/discussion-between-gustavo-kawamoto-and-alejandro-galera).

Answer (score 0):

.env file is used only at docker compose start time by replacing $VARIABLE with values given in .env file. So you cannot expect it to update contents of your myenvfile.env  file. (check [this](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/))

Instead you should declare new environment variable inside docker-compose.yaml like:

```
environment:
    - MY_COMPOSED_ENV_VAR=${SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}_suffix
```

Comment: That's not true. It updates its content if I define variable using `source` command in Linux, and it also updates myenvfile.env if you define env var in Jenkins. The only case myenvfile.env is not updated is in Windows.